# Intersection of two NPDAs

Tags: formal-languages, automata, closure-properties, pushdown-automata

Is there a way to take the interection of two NPDAs?

I can't seem to find anything that can make that happen, but it seems like the type of thing that is should be relatively trival.

Comment: Possible interesting follow-up question: if we *know* that the intersection of the two languages is context-free, can we compute a PDA for it?

Comment: @Raphael, while I agree that it's interesting, I have not the faintest clue of how to go about finding it. Also, I might be naive, but can't a PDA be found for all context-free languages?

Comment: Me neither! This question was not intended for you, but maybe for you to ask on the site? It's certainly true that there *is* a PDA for the intersection (if it's context-free) but whether you can *compute* if from PDA of the original languages is not clear. See for instance [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/21523/98): even if we know that the language of a given PDA is in DCFL, we can not compute a DPDA for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intersection of two context-free languages can be non-context-free. The classical example is
$$ \{ a^n b^n c^m : n,m \geq 0 \} \cap \{ a^m b^n c^n : n,m \geq 0 \} = \{ a^n b^n c^n : n \geq 0 \}. $$
So in general you cannot simulate the intersection of two NPDAs with an NPDA.

Answer (score 2):

Intersection of two NPDA means intersection of their languages.
Of course, Context-free languages are not closed under intersection,
so that you will not generally get a NPDA for the intersection.
If interested in the topic, you may look at [Range Concatenation
Grammars](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/07/30/67/PDF/RR-3611.pdf), which are closed under intersection and parsable in
cubic time. And, of course, they include Context-Free grammars.